# Weird CSS-behaviour

Tags: css, html5

```
            <!DOCTYPE html>
            <html>
            <head>
                <title>PakHet</title>
                <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/basis.css" />
            </head>
            <body>
                <div class="wrapper">
                    <div id='cssmenu'>
                        <ul>
                           <li class="active"><a href='index.html'><span>Start</span></a></li>
                           <li><a href='pakhet.html'><span>Over PakHet</span></a></li>
                           <li><a href='overons.html'><span>Over Ons</span></a></li>
                           <li class='has-sub '><a href='#'><span>Uw pakket</span></a>
                              <ul>
                                 <li><a href='aanmelden.php'><span>Aanmelden</span></a></li>
                                 <li><a href='traceren.php'><span>Traceren</span></a></li>
                              </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="header">
                        <h1>Hier komt de titel van de website</h1>
                    </div>
                    <div class="content">
                        <p>Dit is de tekst van de content. Dit is de indexpagina.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </body>
            </html>
```

And this is the CSS:

```
            /* CSS RESET */

            html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
            h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
            a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
            del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
            small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
            b, u, i, center,
            dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
            fieldset, form, label, legend,
            table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
            article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
            figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
            menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
            time, mark, audio, video, *{
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
                border: 0;
                vertical-align: baseline;
            }
            table {
                border-collapse: collapse;
                border-spacing: 0;
            }

            /* Einde CSS RESET, nu echte code */
            html, body{
                background:url(../images/bg_picture.jpg) fixed no-repeat;
            }
            .wrapper{
                margin:0 auto;
            }
            .header{
                margin:0 auto;
                background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
            }
            .content{
                background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
                width:600px;
                margin:0 auto;
                margin-top:50px;
            }
            .content p{
                color:white;
                text-shadow:1px 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0, 0.5);
                font-family:"Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
            }

            #cssmenu{ height:37px; display:block; padding:0; margin: 0;  border:1px solid; } 
            #cssmenu > ul {list-style:inside none; padding:0; margin:0;} 
            #cssmenu > ul > li {list-style:inside none; padding:0; margin:0; float:left; display:block; position:relative;} 
            #cssmenu > ul > li > a{ outline:none; display:block; position:relative; padding:12px 20px; font:bold 13px/100% "Lucida Grande", Helvetica, sans-serif; text-align:center; text-decoration:none; text-shadow:1px 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0, 0.4); } 
            #cssmenu > ul > li:first-child > a{border-radius:5px 0 0 5px;} 
            #cssmenu > ul > li > a:after{ content:''; position:absolute; border-right:1px solid; top:-1px; bottom:-1px; right:-2px; z-index:99; } 
            #cssmenu ul li.has-sub:hover > a:after{top:0; bottom:0;} 
            #cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub > a:before{ content:''; position:absolute; top:18px; right:6px; border:5px solid transparent; border-top:5px solid #fff; } 
            #cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub:hover > a:before{top:19px;} 
            #cssmenu ul li.has-sub:hover > a{ background:#3f3f3f; border-color:#3f3f3f; padding-bottom:13px; padding-top:13px; top:-1px; z-index:999; } 
            #cssmenu ul li.has-sub:hover > ul, #cssmenu ul li.has-sub:hover > div{display:block;} 
            #cssmenu ul li.has-sub > a:hover{background:#3f3f3f; border-color:#3f3f3f;} 
            #cssmenu ul li > ul, #cssmenu ul li > div{ display:none; width:auto; position:absolute; top:38px; padding:10px 0; background:#3f3f3f; border-radius:0 0 5px 5px; z-index:999; } 
            #cssmenu ul li > ul{width:200px;} 
            #cssmenu ul li > ul li{display:block; list-style:inside none; padding:0; margin:0; position:relative;} 
            #cssmenu ul li > ul li a{ outline:none; display:block; position:relative; margin:0; padding:8px 20px; font:10pt "Lucida Grande", Helvetica, sans-serif; color:#fff; text-decoration:none; text-shadow:1px 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0, 0.5); } 
            #cssmenu, #cssmenu > ul > li > ul > li a:hover{ background:#333333; background:-moz-linear-gradient(top, #333333 0%, #222222 100%); background:-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#333333), color-stop(100%,#222222)); background:-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #333333 0%,#222222 100%); background:-o-linear-gradient(top, #333333 0%,#222222 100%); background:-ms-linear-gradient(top, #333333 0%,#222222 100%); background:linear-gradient(top, #333333 0%,#222222 100%); filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#333333', endColorstr='#222222',GradientType=0 ); } 
            #cssmenu{border-color:#000;} 
            #cssmenu > ul > li > a{border-right:1px solid #000; color:#fff;} 
            #cssmenu > ul > li > a:after{border-color:#444;} 
            #cssmenu > ul > li > a:hover{background:#111;}
            #cssmenu > ul > li.active > a{
                color:orange;
            }
            .header{
                clear:both;
            }
```

The problem is that, whenever I hover on the dropdown-menu, that a 1px margin appears in between the menu and the header. Can I solve that? I can't seem to find the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution is on your `#cssmenu > ul > li` style to set `height: 37px;` because the normal height now is 37px on hover it's 39px I don't see where it's changing. Still looking.

Update

The problem is the style below the border is adding 1px above and below making it 39px, you don't have that set on hover or the class above which I mentioned. Move the height style and you should be fine.

```
#cssmenu {
height: 37px;
display: block;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
border: 1px solid;
```

Comment: Oh, thank you so much! I changed the height to 38px on #cssmenu and it worked! Thank you so much!